# How to find diffrenet ways to implement merge and delete_min operation in binomial heap?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, heaps, priority-queues

I have searched on the internet to find different ways to learn binomial heap operations. What I have found is not quite helpful for me.For example, for delete min operation the algorithm says:

1. Search through the roots of binomial trees and find the smallest key and call it x.Remove the x from the tree.
2. Create a new empty heap H'.
3. Reverse the order of x's children and set the head of H' to point to the head of the resulting list.
4. Merge H' with H.

[image]
On paper everthing seems logical and understandable. I also use some visualization websites-[like this](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/BinomialQueue.html)- to see how things work yet when it comes to coding -especially with C- things start to be seen harder. I could find some codes written in C and I also used them in my projects but I am not satisfied since I couldn't understand them fully.Writing and using these algorithms makes me feel inadequate for my future job.

Also for other algorithms I don't know how to understand algorithms and put them in code-I don't even know how these things will help me in 21st century's corporate world-.

My questions is how should I approach these powerful algorithms and use them?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what your question is and what kind of answer you are looking for.  If you've looked at many resources and none of them met your needs, I'm concerned that anything we write might not, either.  You've told us that they weren't helpful but haven't asked any specific question, so it's not clear what would be helpful.  Perhaps you can spend a little time reflecting on why you are having difficulty, then ask a specific question about some specific aspect you found unclear in some writeup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65869740/781723

Comment: Actually my question here is what is the best approach to understand algorithms and putting them in code? Which sources should I use ? I need some advice. @D.W For example which sources you've found quite helpful